# Dependency Injection causes DbContext runtime error inside Task.Run()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection, .net-core, task-parallel-library

My question is, how can I use Dependency Injection for my DbContext and Repository classes and use them inside multiple tasks?  When I attempt to do this I get the following error; my thought was that I should **not** get this error because I am using AddTransient/ServiceLifetime.Transient to add the DbContext and Repository services:

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

If you prefer, you can download a complete .Net Core console project demonstrating this issue at [this shared Google Drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oCvinzP8XraKmYSGH6WVuVStxDttaoAV/view?usp=sharing).  In the appsettings.json file change "SQLDev01" to the name of any SQL Server you have access to and it should run with no other changes. I will also include enough code below to illustrate the issue.

Here is my appsettings.json:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyConnectionString": "Data Source=SqlDev01; Initial Catalog=master; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
  }
}
```

Here is my Program.cs.  I am using AddTransient to register my custom classes and ServiceLifetime.Transient to register the DBContext.  Since Transient creates a new instance each time it is requested I assumed this would work even if multiple Tasks are launched:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using MyTest.Library;
using MyTest.Library.Data;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace MyTest.Host
{
class Program
{
    public static ServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            IServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(configuration);

            services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("MyConnectionString"))
                    .UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking)
                , ServiceLifetime.Transient);

            services.AddTransient<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();

            services.AddTransient<IMain, Main>();

            ServiceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();

            var main = ServiceProvider.GetService<IMain>();
            main.Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            ServiceProvider?.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
}
```

This is the Dependency-injected class that generates the above-mentioned runtime error.  The commented-out portion runs successfully; the runtime error is entirely due to use of the TPL:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using MyTest.Library.Data;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyTest.Library
{
public interface IMain
{
    void Run();
}
public class Main : IMain
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly IMyRepository _myRepository;

    public Main(IConfiguration configuration,
        IMyRepository myRepository)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _myRepository = myRepository;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        /*
        var getFromDatabase = _myRepository.GetFromDatabase();
        if (getFromDatabase == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("getFromDatabase == null");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"name={getFromDatabase.name} number={getFromDatabase.number }");
        }
        */

        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Task task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var getFromDatabase = _myRepository.GetFromDatabase();
                if (getFromDatabase == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("getFromDatabase == null");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"name={getFromDatabase.name} number={getFromDatabase.number }");
                }
            });
            tasks.Add(task);
        }

        try
        {
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            foreach (var task in tasks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{task.Status}, {task.Exception?.ToString()}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here is the repository class that gets Dependency-injected, it reads from the master database:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyTest.Library.Models;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyTest.Library.Data
{
public interface IMyRepository
{
    GetFromDatabase GetFromDatabase();
}
public class MyRepository : IMyRepository
{
    private readonly MyDbContext _myDbContext;

    public MyRepository(MyDbContext myDbContext)
    {
        _myDbContext = myDbContext;
    }

    public GetFromDatabase GetFromDatabase()
    {
        const string sql = "SELECT TOP 1 name, number FROM dbo.spt_values";
        return _myDbContext.GetFromDatabase.FromSql(sql).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
}
```

Here is my DbContext class that gets Dependency-injected:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using MyTest.Library.Models;

namespace MyTest.Library.Data
{
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public virtual  DbQuery<GetFromDatabase> GetFromDatabase { get; set; }
}
}
```

I realize I could simply new up a DbContext and MyRepository and avoid the runtime error, but I'd much rather use Dependency Injection.  Is there any way to use Dependency Injection, launch multiple Tasks, and avoid this runtime error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to create a factory

```
//...omitted for brevity

services.AddTransient<IMyRepository, MyRepository>();
services.AddTransient<Func<IMyRepository>>(sp => () => sp.GetRequiredService<IMyRepository>());

//...omitted for brevity
```

And inject that into the dependent.

```
public class Main : IMain {
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
    private readonly Func<IMyRepository> factory;

    public Main(IConfiguration configuration,
        Func<IMyRepository> factory) {
        _configuration = configuration;
        this.factory = factory;
    }

//...omitted for brevity
```

Use the factory to get your independent instances for execution.

```
//...omitted for brevity

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    Task task = Task.Run(() => {
        var getFromDatabase = factory().GetFromDatabase();
        if (getFromDatabase == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("getFromDatabase == null");
        } else {
            Console.WriteLine($"name={getFromDatabase.name} number={getFromDatabase.number }");
        }
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

//...omitted for brevity
```

I would suggest making your repository disposable and have it release its resources when no longer in scope.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "create a factory" and "Use the factory".  Sorry to ask, I'm new to .Net Core and DI both.

Comment: The factory in this case is a factory delegate/function that will create your desired object when invoked.

Comment: @Nkosi you have me on the right track, but when I add your suggestions to my code I get this error when I call Main.Run():  System.InvalidOperationException: No service for type 'MyTest.Library.Data.IMyRepository' has been registered.

Comment: Did you register your repository? My suggestion about the factory is in addition to what you already had

Comment: @Nkosi bingo! Thank you for your help.